# Two scripts colliding, but only on mobile - Login window + Slidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

The problem I'm having is quite specific, usually I'd be able to figure it out myself, but since it only occurs on mobile and chrome device mode I think I need some help. I'm using two scrips for my site, one for a mobile ['slidebar'](http://plugins.adchsm.me/slidebars/), and one script for a [signup/login pop-up window] ( codyhouse(.)co/gem/loginsignup-modal-window/ can't post more than one real link because of just signing up).

When below 600px, the slidebar will activate and all the navigation buttons 'move' into the slidebar along with the sign in. When clicking the sign in button, which is in its own, separate div, the slidebar closes and the signup/login window opens. Now here's the problem: once you're on mobile, or in the chrome device mode, for some strange reason the sign up window refuses to open if the 'close class' for the slidebar is present.

I will demonstrate more thoroughly below:

The html in question: `

```
        <div class="main-nav sb-close">
            <ul class="sb-menu">
                <li><a href="#0">Sign in</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>`
```

main-nav is the target for the signup/login window, and when clicked it will set the window to visible.

sb-close is the target for closing the sidebar.

JavaScript code which opens the window:

```
$main_nav.on('click', function(event){

        if( $(event.target).is($main_nav) ) {
            // on mobile open the submenu
            $(this).children('ul').toggleClass('is-visible');
        } else {
            // on mobile close submenu
            $main_nav.children('ul').removeClass('is-visible');
            //show modal layer
            $form_modal.addClass('is-visible'); 
            //show the selected form
            ( $(event.target).is('.cd-signup') ) ? signup_selected() : login_selected();
        }

    });
```

Live example: http://test321.com.preview.binero.se/

If you simply resize in your web-browser and try to click the 'sign in' button, it will slide back and the window will pop up, just like it should. But if you either go into chrome device mode, or access it from your mobile, you will see that it will only slide back, but won't open. It seems like it's connected to the touch controls somehow, overlapping elements maybe, I just don't know.

I only know these scripts on a very basic level, so if there's anyone that can pin-point what could be wrong or, even better, has used these scripts before, I'd love some help.

If there is anything else I can provide, just ask.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: You aren't using the correct mark-up for the mobile. Coz this happens only in Android Browser and not all the browsers.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Sorry for my noobiness, but what exactly do you mean?

Comment: In the default browser, this is what I get. http://i.imgur.com/CTuNf1w.jpg

Comment: @PraveenKumar huh, that's a whole other problem, haven't seen that before. How would I go about fixing that?

Comment: LoL... @Kazumi I guess you will have a pretty big time. I will have a look at your code soon. Right now busy! Let's see if others are responding.